# Click email verification link to open app

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am building a mobile app with Meteor. When a user signs up, I send him a verification email. When he opens the email and clicks the link, he's redirected to `myapp.com/`, which is a mobile web version of my app. Instead, when he clicks the link, I want the app to open so he can start the app right away.

I thought it was possible by setting a custom URL scheme. To set it, I can use this [cordova plugin](https://forums.meteor.com/t/custom-url-scheme-for-meteor-cordova-apps/3312/2). However, what if the user opens the verification link on the computer? Is there a way to redirect him to the mobile web page when he opens it on a computer, and open the app otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remark: I tested this flow and found that a custom url scheme does not always works and open the mobile application depending on the email app used by the user. 
So, I ended up with a "normal" web link in the verification email that open the page in the browser and immediately redirects the user (through the router) to the custom url scheme, which works quite well.

Concerning your question, I don't see any other way to check if the user is on a mobile device or a desktop device than checking for the user agent. 
Before redirecting to the custom url scheme I would check if it is a mobile browser and then redirect to the custom url scheme, or if it appears to be a desktop browser, continue to the page.

It seems that there are some packages out there for proper device detection, like this one: 
https://atmospherejs.com/mystor/device-detection

Comment: Hi! That's an interesting approach. Please tell me if I understood it correctly. When the user opens myapp.com/verified, then in my route I can just route them to myapp://something?

Comment: Yes this is the idea, because some emails apps seem to not support custom URL, but a browser redirect does the trick. (but I am afraid that there is no perfect solution)

Comment: There's one more gotcha. When the app is opened, I want to redirect to somewhere inside the app but it seems I lose reactivity the first time the app is opened. Does listening to Cordova `resume` event work for you?

Comment: if the app was in background, maybe you lose the connection to the server. Consequences are that you have to wait for the next retry which is getting longer after each retry but it's invisible... To solve this problem I created a package (https://atmospherejs.com/255kb/meteor-status) alerting when the connection is lost, and allowing the user to reconnect manually. I also know that there is a package that automatically reconnects on cordova resume event, but I don't remember the name. You can also add a listener on this event by yourself and reconnect with `Meteor.reconnect()`

Comment: But how do I detect if the user has the app installed? He could have used the regular mobile web page to register. Then a redirect to myapp:// gives an error, right?

Comment: Right, within the app you can check if an app is installed (I think there is a plug-in for that), but if you load the link in the browser first there is no way to detect if an app is installed, and the redirection to a custom URL scheme will not trigger anything. Maybe dealing with such flow in the browser is the way to go.